# Looping over multiple values and storing results in a data frame

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to calculate some macronutrients values obtained from a reference table. These are my inputs:

DF1. The values indicate the amount of portions consumed per day, on a monthly basis.

```
id  Cow Milk    Soy Milk    Yoghurt (...)
001 0.07        0           0        ...
002 0           0.4         0        ...
003 0.07        0.07        0.13     ...
004 2.5         0           0        ...
... ...         ...         ...      ...
```

My reference table looks like this:

DF2. Reference values

```
Food      Kcal   Proteins Trans Fat Satured Fat (5 more columns)
Cow Milk  91.50  4.95     4.95      3.12        ...
Soy Milk  49.50  4.20     2.85      1.80        ...
Yoghurt   122.00 7.00     6.60      0.18        ...
......    ...    ...      ...       ...         ...
```

What I need to do is:

1. Multiply *portions value* of the food times the corresponding value of that food in the reference table for each variable (i.e., kcal, protein, fat...).
2. Sum all the values obtained for each food in the same variable (sum all kcal, sum all the protein...) for that id.
3. Consolidate in one data.frame.

So, for example, the *kcal* and *protein* values only for id 001 so far should be:

```
id001
  kcal
   (0.07*91.5) + (0*49.5) + (0*122) = 6.405
  protein
   (0.07*4.95) + (0*4.2)  + (0*7)   = 0.3465
  ...
```

And I need to calculate that for all the foods, all the other variables of reference table for that same id and for dozens of other ids.

My final table should look like this:

| id | Total Kcal | Total Proteins | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 6.405 | 0.3465 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I was thinking of implementing a loop:

```
results <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:ncol(df1)) {
  kcal <- df1[,i] * df2[i,]
  results$kcal <- rbind(results$kcal, kcal)
}
```

But I don't even know how to make it iterate through each variable while maintaining `df1[,i]` position, nor make it sum the values once has finalized... never have done such a complex thing before. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you add `dput(head(DF1,10))` and `dput(head(DF2,10))` to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` option

```r
library(tidyverse)
DF1 %>% 
    pivot_longer(-id, names_to = "Food", values_to = "portion") %>%
    left_join(DF2 %>% pivot_longer(-Food), by = "Food") %>%
    group_by(id, name) %>%
    summarise(value = sum(value * portion), .groups = "drop") %>%
    pivot_wider(names_prefix = "Total ")
## A tibble: 4 × 5
#     id `Total Kcal` `Total Proteins` `Total Satured Fat` `Total Trans Fat`
#  <int>        <dbl>            <dbl>               <dbl>             <dbl>
#1     1         6.40            0.347               0.218             0.347
#2     2        19.8             1.68                0.72              1.14 
#3     3        25.7             1.55                0.368             1.40 
#4     4       229.             12.4                 7.8              12.4
```

Please note that there is an error in your example calculation for `Total Proteins` for `id001`:

> (0.07 * 4.95) + (0 * 4.2)  + (0 * 7)   = <s>0.198</s> 0.3465

Explanation: We reshape both `DF1` and `DF2` from wide to long, then do a left-join of long `DF1` with long `DF2` by `"Food"`. We can then `group_by(id, name)` (where `name` gives the name of the quantity from `DF2`: Kcal, Proteins, Trans Fat, etc.) and calculate the desired quantities as the `sum(value * portion)`, respectively. Finally, we reshape again from long to wide, and add the prefix `"Total "` to the new wide columns.

---

### Sample data

```r
DF1 <- read.table(text = "id  'Cow Milk'    'Soy Milk'    Yoghurt
001 0.07        0           0
002 0           0.4         0
003 0.07        0.07        0.13
004 2.5         0           0", header = T, check.names = F)

DF2 <- read.table(text = "Food      Kcal   Proteins 'Trans Fat' 'Satured Fat'
'Cow Milk'  91.50  4.95     4.95      3.12
'Soy Milk'  49.50  4.20     2.85      1.80
Yoghurt   122.00 7.00     6.60      0.18", header = T, check.names = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to achieve this using `for` loop:

```
results = data.frame() 
for (i in 1:nrow(DF1)) {
  df_composition_for_id_i = DF2 %>% filter(Food %in% names(DF1[i,])[DF1[i,]>0])
  quantity_food = t(DF1[i,-1])[t(DF1[i,-1])>0]
  df_transform = sweep(df_composition_for_id_i[,-1], 1, quantity_food, `*`)
  Total = c(i, colSums(df_transform))
  names(Total)[1]= "id"
  results = rbind(results, Total)
}
names(results) = names(DF2)
names(results)[1] = "id"

> results
  id    Kcal Proteins Trans Fat Satured Fat
1  1   6.405   0.3465    0.3465      0.2184
2  2  19.800   1.6800    1.1400      0.7200
3  3  25.730   1.5505    1.4040      0.3678
4  4 228.750  12.3750   12.3750      7.8000
```

Using this for loop you can feed a dataframe with more columns in your DF2 (eg. `carbohydrates`, `vitamins`, ...) which will be computed in the loop without more intervention.

### Explanation:

In the `for` loop the first `df_composition_for_id_i` is a dataframe with only the nutrient present in the current iteration for example when `i=3`:

```
i=3
df_composition_for_id_i = DF2 %>% filter(Food %in% names(DF1[i,])[DF1[i,]>0])
df_composition_for_id_i
      Food  Kcal Proteins Trans Fat Satured Fat
1 Cow Milk  91.5     4.95      4.95        3.12
2 Soy Milk  49.5     4.20      2.85        1.80
3  Yoghurt 122.0     7.00      6.60        0.18
```

`quantity_food` is the quantity of each nutrient that will be pass to multiply by row

```
quantity_food
[1] 0.07 0.07 0.13
```

`df_transform` take the first element created in this loop (`df_composition_for_id_i`) and then multiply by row with the second (`quantity_food`) (excluding the `Food` name) using the `sweep` function:

```
df_transform = sweep(df_composition_for_id_i[,-1], 1, quantity_food, `*`)
df_transform
    Kcal Proteins Trans Fat Satured Fat
1  6.405   0.3465    0.3465      0.2184
2  3.465   0.2940    0.1995      0.1260
3 15.860   0.9100    0.8580      0.0234
```

Lastly, the sum of this is calculated and id added with some tidy up for the naming and binded by row on the new dataframe:

```
Total = c(i, colSums(df_transform))
names(Total)[1]= "id"
results = rbind(results, Total)

  id  Kcal Proteins Trans Fat Satured Fat
1  3 25.73   1.5505     1.404      0.3678
```

Comment: It is useful to visualize the loop and the explanation. I should note that this method is slower in comparison with the other answer (using %>%), but it yield the same results. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, looping through a dataframe is not optimal, just wanted to show your idea was viable ;)